# How to store the URL and separate each of the word

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I know how to store the URL parameters using the below JavaScript but is there a way to store each word after the slash.

Example: I have the URL:
http://localhost:9000/Database/Users/username/passwordReset?key=123214asdas2321

Let's say I want to store the 'username' from above URL, any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function () {
                var url = document.location.href,
                    params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'),
                    data = {}, tmp;
                for (var i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++) {
                     tmp = params[i].split('=');
                     data[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
                }
                var wordKey = data.key;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with regexp ?

Is that what you want ?

```js
var url = 'http://localhost:9000/Database/Users/randomusername/passwordReset?key=123214asdas2321',
regexp = /\/Users\/([^/]+)/,
result = url.match(regexp);

console.log(result[1]);
```

Comment: awesome let me try and get back @Steeve

Comment: That doesn't work with `http://localhost:9000/Database/Users/randomusername` because it has no slash after the username. Use `match('/Users/([^/]+)')` it works better!

Comment: True, better to use your regexp, i update my answer;

Answer (score 1):

You need to explore a little the browser object "window.location", with a split you will be able to find want you want.

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/window/location

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getUsername(url) {
  var split = url.split("/");
  for (var i = 1; i < split.length; i++) {
    if (split[i - 1] === "Users") return split[i];
  }
}
```

```html
Enter url:<br>
<input type="text" style="width: 500px"
    onkeyup="console.log(getUsername(this.value));"/>
```

Comment: thank you will definitely get back after trying all the possible approaches.

Answer (score 1):

The logic is similar. Instead of using split() with '?' or '&', you can use with '/'. You can try something like this:

```
function getUrlArray(url){
    var idx = str.indexOf('?');
        if (idx > 0) {
            str = str.substring(0,idx);
        }
    var strArray = str.split('/');
    return strArray;
}
```

With the code above, you get an array of the url hierarchy params. Only keep in mind that the position 0 will always be the main address (*i.e www.anything.com*), so you might need to start at position 1 when searching for something.